# Ошибка: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import speech_recognition as sr

for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name)
```

Мне показывает ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

после строки `import speech_recognition as sr`

Comment: А что с ними не так? У вас скобки закрывающей для `print` не хватает, скорее - это да.

Comment: Мне показывает ошибку SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement после строки import speech_recognition as sr

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Это не отступы, а скорее - незакрытая скобка и чехарда с кавычками...
Попробуйте так:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name '{1}' found for 'Microphone(device_index={0})'".format(index, name))
```

и используйте f-строки(с версии 3.6 в Python): нагляднее и проще

```
for i, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print(f"Microphone with name {name} found for 'Microphone(device_index={i})")
```